# html5 tutorial >30 Styling the Default and Progress Bars weird?

Tags: css, html

[image]

[image]
[image]

I used the exactly same code from thenewboston Html5 tutorial, class 30. but I do not understand why the #defaultBar and the #progressBar went outside of the #skin. As the tutorial they should inside of the #skin (I use chrome).What mistakes I did? Please Help!!

this is the tutorial link https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=10&video=16949

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS :) It's because of the float.

```css
nav::after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I changed those three elements attributes,it seems like working now.
 I was thinking whole night when i sleep and I found one way to fixed it.It was make #nav to be a box. put #buttons and #progressBar inside. 
I do not know why Bucky's code not works in my laptop ,but I think as long as it looks the same will be fine. hope it helpful for other people who stuck in class 30. [image]